# Angular2 service not working when component variable type is explicitly set

Tags: angular, service

For some reason I am getting an error

`Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in http://localhost:3000/app/calendars/cal-nav.component.html:5:7 caused by: Cannot read property 'selectedDate' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'selectedDate' of undefined`

However, when I do not define the type and instead instantiate the variable like this `workingData = {selectedDate : "nonsense"};` then service works property and displays the date. **Why is this, and what's the best way to manage?**

cal-nav.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { WorkingData } from '../working-data';
import { WorkingDataService } from '../working-data.service';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'cal-nav',
  templateUrl: 'cal-nav.component.html',
  providers: [WorkingDataService]
})
export class CalNavComponent implements OnInit{

  // this is where the issue is apparently
  workingData : WorkingData;

  constructor(private _workingDataService: WorkingDataService) { }

  getWorkingData(): void {
    this._workingDataService.getWorkingData().then(workingData => this.workingData = workingData);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getWorkingData();
    console.log(this.workingData);
  }
}
```

working-data.ts

```
export interface WorkingData{
  selectedDate: string,
  targetDate: string,
  selectedExercise: string
}
```

mock-working-data.ts

```
import {WorkingData} from './working-data';

export const WORKINGDATA: WorkingData = {
  selectedDate: "Nov 1",
  targetDate: "Nov 11",
  selectedExercise: "Squat"
};
```

Comment: Either 1) It's an async issue or 2) Your service isn't returning any data.  `Cannot read property 'selectedDate' of undefined` means that the variable workingData hasn't been set yet.  When you initiate it with a selectedDate value, then using workingData.selectedDate obviously returns the value that you set.

Comment: @VtoCorleone It must be the former. I `console.log()` the data after I assign the value from the service and it displays `undefined` once and then it displays the correct object from the service. If it is an async issue, how do I go about fixing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `workingData` is not resolved yet when the view is rendered, as it resolves asynchronously. Either use an `*ngIf` to first check that `workingData` is not undefined:

```
<div *ngIf="workingData">
  <!-- other stuff using workingData -->
</div>
```

OR use the Angular safe navigation operator `?.` which is a fluent and convenient way to guard against null and undefined values in property paths. Here it is, protecting against a view render failure if the `workingData` object is null:

```
<stuff>{{ workingData?.selectedData }}</stuff>
```